# Primary key and FK constraints on partitioned tables

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-14

I have 2 tables with more than 10 million rows.

```
create table TBL1 (
   GUID       UUID                 not null default gen_random_uuid(),
   DT         DATE                 not null,
   ...
   constraint tbl1_pk primary key (GUID, DT)
)
partition by RANGE (dt);

create table TBL2 (
   GUID       UUID                 not null default gen_random_uuid(),
   DT         DATE                 not null,
   TBL1_GUID  UUID                 not null,
   ...
   constraint tbl2_pk primary key (GUID, DT)
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (dt);

alter table TBL2
   add constraint FK_TBL2__TBL1 foreign key (DT, TBL1_GUID)
      references TBL1 (DT, GUID)
      on delete restrict on update restrict;
```

There are 24 partition by month to each tables.

Does the order columns in the primary key matter?
Does the order columns in the foreign key matter?
Do I need to create fk for each partition, not on hole table?
Queries are running slowly.

Queries are running slowly.

Comment: How does a query look like? when you are selecting a date (`DT`), then it should be the first field in the index. Currently doing `SELECT * FROM TBL1 WHERE DT='2023-04-08'` would need a full table scan to find the needed records.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment about your slow running queries, since you didn't include the queries nor their `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output.

But I have a couple of recommendations for you:

- Don't define a primary key on `(guid, dt)`.  Rather, define a primary key on `guid` alone for each partition. That is closer to what you'd actually want: a globally unique constraint on `guid`.
- Don't define foreign keys pointing to partitioned tables, because they will keep you from detaching partitions of the referenced table. Instead, define foreign key constraints between the corresponding partitions.
- If you plan to join on the common partitioning key `guid`, set `enable_partitionwise_join` to `on`, so that PostgreSQL joins on the partition level, which will normally perform better.